# How can I calculate the time between 2 Dates in typescript

Tags: date, typescript

This works in Javascript

```
new Date() - new Date("2013-02-20T12:01:04.753Z")
```

But in typescript I can't rest two new Dates

```
Date("2013-02-20T12:01:04.753Z")
```

Don't work because paremater not match date signature

Answer (score 261):

Use the [`getTime` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) to get the time in total milliseconds since 1970-01-01, and subtract those:

```
var time = new Date().getTime() - new Date("2013-02-20T12:01:04.753Z").getTime();
```

Comment: I think you're mixing up getTime() and valueOf(). According to the docs, getTime() "Gets the time value in milliseconds." whereas it's valueOf() which "Returns the stored time value in milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC."

Comment: Both do the same:
`new Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).valueOf()  
// returns 2674800000  
new Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).getTime()  
// returns 2674800000`

Comment: @KenLyon From MDN getTime documentation: _You can use this method to help assign a date and time to another Date object. **This method is functionally equivalent to the valueOf() method.**_

Comment: A tip, instead of using `new Date().getTime()` use `Date.now()` so you don't make new objects unnecessarily.

Comment: Apart from the two methods being functionally equivalent, `getTime()` is also much faster than `valueOf()`.

Answer (score 179):

This is how it should be done in typescript:

```
(new Date()).valueOf() - (new Date("2013-02-20T12:01:04.753Z")).valueOf()
```

Better readability:

```
      var eventStartTime = new Date(event.startTime);
      var eventEndTime = new Date(event.endTime);
      var duration = eventEndTime.valueOf() - eventStartTime.valueOf();
```

Comment: This is the most correct approach, since javascript is using "valueOf" internally when doing arithmetic on objects. Typescript should be clever enough (unfortunataly, it isn't yet) to support this since it already knows that the valueOf method for a Date returns a number as defined in lib.d.ts

Comment: Interestingly typescript is so clever now that even if you don't define `eventStartTime` and `eventEndTime` that duration gets typed as a `number` (meaning if you literally take the third line of code here by itself here duration will be a number)

Answer (score 49):

In order to calculate the difference you have to put the `+` operator,

that way `typescript` converts the dates to numbers.

```
+new Date()- +new Date("2013-02-20T12:01:04.753Z")
```

From there you can make a formula to convert the difference to `minutes` or `hours`.

Answer (score 45):

It doesn't work because `Date - Date` relies on exactly the kind of type coercion TypeScript is designed to prevent.

There is a workaround for this using the `+` prefix:

```
var t = Date.now() - +(new Date("2013-02-20T12:01:04.753Z"));
```

Or, if you prefer not to use `Date.now()`:

```
var t = +(new Date()) - +(new Date("2013-02-20T12:01:04.753Z"));
```

[See discussion here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170506161203/http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/156).

Or see Siddharth Singh's answer, below, for a more elegant solution using `valueOf()`

Comment: Approving the link edit because, due to the closure of CodePlex, the original discussion is no longer available at the existing link; unless there's some blanket objection to using web.archive.org, this does not damage or deface the original post in any way, but rather preserves its meaning.

Answer (score 9):

```
// TypeScript

const today = new Date();
const firstDayOfYear = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 0, 1);

// Explicitly convert Date to Number
const pastDaysOfYear = ( Number(today) - Number(firstDayOfYear) );
```

Answer (score 1):

OP wanted a time as the result:

```
return new Date(this.submitted.valueOf() - this.created.valueOf())
```