# Does GraphQL/graphene have a way to represent a time interval?

Tags: graphql, timedelta, graphene-python

Many, if not most modern programming languages have a way to represent time intervals or duration. Go has `time.Duration`, Python's got `datetime.timedelta` and even Typescript has [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980014/how-can-i-calculate-the-time-between-2-dates-in-typescript). GraphQL supports `DateTime`, but I haven't been able to find anything for representing duration. Does GraphQL have anything comparable?

Comment: GraphQL has no notion of "duration", in the same way it has nothing related with dates. You can encode dates as strings, or with custom data types, and you could do the same with durations, for example sending a number representing an appropriate time span (number of seconds or minutes, for example).

Comment: Care to submit that as an answer so I can credit you?