# Calculate duration between start time and end time in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting start time and end time using date pipe

```
 this.startTime=this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'hh:mm');

 this.endTime=this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'hh:mm');
```

output is like this : start time - `01:14`
end time - `01:15`

i want to calculate the difference between start time and end time, for current case it should return 1.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I calculate the time between 2 Dates in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980014/how-can-i-calculate-the-time-between-2-dates-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it will have this date in form of strings, and you want to have difference in minutes:-

```
function findDiff(startTime, endTime) {
  const start = startTime.split(':');
  const end = endTime.split(':');

  let totalMinDifference = ((parseInt(end[0]) * 60) +  parseInt(end[1])) - ((parseInt(start[0]) * 60) +  parseInt(start[1]));

  return totalMinDifference ; // if want to have result difference in seconds multiply with 60
}
```

How to use :-

```
findDiff('01:14', '01:15')
```

Comment: If you have two DateTimes, simply substract the date1.getTime()-date2.getTime()